# Could not find class XXX referenced from method XXX.<YYY> Just appeared below Android 5.0

Tags: android

app can run if the system is higher than 5.0. But when the system is below 5.0, for example 4.4 or 4.0，app can not run.for example

```
`E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'retrofit2.Call', referenced from method com.ionicframework.stemiapp751652.base.BaseActivity.callCancel`
```

All can not find the class from external libraries.for example

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

Thank you for seeing my question and giving me some advice.

Comment: what is the minimumSdk version of your app in gradle??

Comment: minimumSdk version is 17